# How to get sum of particular rows of specific colom from table mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sum, calculated-columns

Here I am trying to get total of 5 specific rows out of 15 rows from specific column of table in mysql.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(column) FROM Table WHERE business_name= 'my business'";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

print_r ($row);

Array ( [SUM(rating)] => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `Count(*)`

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'column' FROM Table WHERE business_name= 'my business'";
```

Comment: When I go with option 1 its work awesome but when I go with option 2 which I want to do its giving me 0 as result

option 1  :  $business = $value['HDFC Bank Ltd'];
//echo $business;

option 2  :  $business = $value['business_name'];
//echo $business; (When echo get value store in variable)

(but when I put that variable in sql it's not working)

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'rating' FROM listings_reviews WHERE business_name= '$business'";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

//print_r ($row) ;

$rating = implode($row);

echo $rating;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an alias. `$sql = "SELECT SUM(column) as ss FROM Table WHERE business_name= 'my business'";` and then fetch the data using `$row['ss']`

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(column) as ss FROM Table WHERE business_name= 'my business'";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
echo $row['ss'];
```

I hope it helps!